# How can I filter a List with linq based on a value of a list within?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list

I have a model that has a list of a list:
List 1 = States
List 2 = Zip Codes

Zip Codes has a property that sees if it's been checked (bool) & I am displaying all the states and a list of zip codes they could select the zip codes from a list of checkboxes and when the model gets posted back on HttpPost then checked gets set to true.

I need to filter the list of states to pull back only the states that have zip codes checked. I tried this but it comes back null:

```
var temp = States.Where(a => a.ZipCodes.Where(b => b.Checked == true).Any()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove that nested `Where()` call and make it

```
var temp = States.Where(a => a.ZipCodes.Any(b => b.Checked)).ToList();
```

Comment: it still came back null

Comment: @cxwilson, do you have any zipcodes checked in that list? make sure the condition holds

Comment: yepp I had 4 checked